# BigQuery execution order when joining

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to understand the execution and data retrieval logic in BigQuery so that I can write more efficient queries. Imagine I have the following tables, each containing a big number of rows:

- `table_a`: join key `id`, partitioned by `date_a` and clustered by `cluster_a`
- `table_b`: join key `id`, partitioned by `date_b` and clustered by `cluster_b`

According to SQL execution order, we first evaluate the `FROM` and `JOIN`s statements to determine the total working set of data that is being queried, and then we evaluate the `WHERE` clauses to filter data.

So, let's say I have this query:

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT
    id,
    ta.date_a AS date,
    ta.cluster_a,
    tb.cluster_b
FROM table_a AS ta
LEFT JOIN table_b AS tb
USING (id)
WHERE
    ta.date_a = '2022-11-01'
    AND tb.date_b = '2022-11-01'
    AND ta.cluster_a = 'a'
    AND tb.cluster_b = 'b'
```

and this other one, returning the same output:

**Query 2:**

```
SELECT
    id,
    ta.date_a AS date,
    ta.cluster_a,
    tb.cluster_b
FROM (
    SELECT
        id,
        date_a,
        cluster_a
    FROM table_a
    WHERE
        date_a = '2022-11-01'
        AND cluster_a = 'a'
) AS ta
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        id,
        cluster_b
    FROM table_b
    WHERE
        date_b = '2022-11-01'
        AND cluster_b = 'b'
) AS tb
USING (id)
```

Considering these two queries:

- Is **query 2** more efficient as I am filtering the `FROM` and `JOIN` clause before joining? Or does **query 1** also filter the number of rows with the `WHERE` clause before doing the join?
- Is there any other way in which I could improve this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, and this could be apply to almost any database:

1. it is better to have smaller tables before join
2. Let the large table join the small table rather than the large table joining the large table.
3. Avoid unnecessary columns in SELECT clause.

So query2 will perform better since the filters are applied before the join, resulting in smaller sets.

Comment: I somehow forgot to upvote and mark it as correct, sorry! Could you elaborate more about point number 2? Do you mean that big tables should be on top, and smaller on bottom? For example, if I have table A (small) and table B (large) and I want to get some columns from B to A, the natural approach would be `FROM A LEFT JOIN B`, but is it more efficient to do `FROM B RIGHT JOIN A` to place the big table first?

Comment: Yes, before joining tables you should apply as many filters as possible. In general it is better to join small tables rather than larger ones.

And yes, large tables should be on the left side.